Migrating to a bigger hard drive with RAID
I have my desktop computer with a software RAID 1 that I have built few years ago. It was created with the Intel Rapid Storage Technology software. It is working ok, but space is running out.
The RAID doesn't contain the operating system (Win11), that is installed on an M2 SSD. The OS on the M2 are drive C, and this RAID is drive D. This RAID is two identical 7200 4T Hard drives.
Assuming I have two new Identical Hard drives with a larger capacity (12TB)
What is the process of creating the same RAID 1 , with the new hard drives and cloning the content of the old drive onto it without loosing the timestamps or modifying their created / access dates?


Please focus on a single question. Superuser requires a single question per post. First, make sure you have a good backup. Have you tried creating a new RAID array alongside the old one? It seems like it would be a pretty simple thing to try.

Question edited, anyway I haven't tried yet, are you sure it possible with the Intel Rapid Storage ?  the main thing is the integrity of the data,

Removing the numbers from in front of the questions doesn't make 2 questions one. Just get rid of the "how do I copy" because that question will only come after you solve the first one, and it is very likely that question has already been answered here before. Migrating data is a pretty well documented process. Have you done even web searching to tell whether you can create more than one RAID using RST? That seems like a good place to start, and is certainly less effort than typing a question here.

yea its not easy to find if its possible to have two RAID on RTS , I did try

Did you open the RST software and look?

I see no relevant information suggesting the use of Intel RST.  It’s not clear if it’s a hardware RAID or a software RAID. Please add the relevant information to conclusively provide that determination. It’s tagged software RAID but that doesn’t necessarily mean anything. We need more information specifically from Intel RST itself if your actual using that solution

It's a software RST, I'll edit the post

detailed answer i got from Intel support:
before you start anything do a backup in 2 places!!!! best with robocopy so dates wont change on the files!
see here:
see intel's response here
Thank you for posting on the Intel️® communities. We understand you are looking for recommendations for upgrading your RAID 1 volume.
Here are our recommended steps to move the RAID 1 volume to larger drives. This procedure will not require re-installation of the operating system and will not compromise the current information on the RAID 1 volume:
 - Turn off the system and remove one of the drives.
 - Replace it with a drive larger in capacity.
 - Turn on the system and boot into Windows*.
 - Open the Intel® Rapid Storage Technology user interface (Start > All Programs > Intel > Intel® Rapid Storage Technology).
 - Click Rebuild to another disk.
 - Select the newly added drive and click Rebuild.
 - Allow the rebuild to complete.
 - Restart the system and enter the Intel® Rapid Storage Technology option ROM by pressing CTRL+I when prompted.
 - Click Reset Disks to Non-RAID.
 - You may see a dialog box warning you of data loss. This warning does not apply to RAID 1; you will still be able to access your data.
 - Click Yes to confirm.
 - Click Exit and shut off the system.
 - Remove the original (smaller) drive from the system. This will leave only the new (higher capacity) drive, acting as a single drive (it is no longer part of a RAID volume).
 - Turn on the system and boot into Windows. You may need to change the drive priority in the BIOS.
 - From within Windows, use the Windows computer management tools or a third-party partitioning software to resize the drive partition so that it uses the entire capacity of the drive.
 - Turn off the system and attach the second large drive.
 - Turn on the system and boot into Windows.
 - Open the Intel Rapid Storage Technology user interface and click the Create icon.
 - Follow the prompts to create a new RAID 1 volume. Your data will then be migrated from the single large drive to the new RAID 1 volume.

Best regards,
Jean O.
Intel Customer Support Technician
